# Counting one to one function for this sets

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functions

How many one-to-one functions like $f$ there are from $A=\{1,2,...,9\}$ to $B=\{1,2,....,88\}$ so that for each $a $ and $b$ 
$$f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$

Comment: **Hints** Obviously $f(1)=1$, The fact that for each $a,b$ we have $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$ means that if we know the factorization of $n$ then we can compute $f(n)$. THis means that $f$ is determined uniquely by its values at the prime numbers. Hence $f$ is determined uniquely by the value of: 
$$f(2),f(3),f(5),f(7)$$
But here again we $f(8)\leq 88$ implies that $  f(2)^3\leq 88$ and hence $2\leq f(2)\leq 4$ the same way you can prove that $f(3)f(3)\leq 88$ so you must have $f(3)\leq 9$

Comment: @Elaqqad - nice answer! About the only thing left is to determine whether $f(3)$ and $f(2)$ can be chosen independently of each other, and that is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Thank you.  Then at all we have 5 functions?

Comment: @Marconius this is not an answer, and $f(2)$ and $f(3)$ can not be chosed independly for instance we must have $f(2)\neq f(3)$, the condition "one-to-one" is very complicated to formalize this way I think that one should ignore it in the first computation and in the next step we compute the number of not one to one functions